# Asimov's psychohistory and real math

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

In Asimov's [Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series), math based [psychohistory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_(fictional)) is referenced to model and predict not less than the history of the human kind.

Given that is of course just fiction, is there any existing mathematical approach going anyhow in this direction?

Comment: Very little except in isolated rather narrow areas.

Comment: If such a thing were a real science, it would be a discipline of social science or psychology, not of mathematics.

Comment: The spelling used by the author in English was *Asimov*.

Comment: In 1963, Edward Lorenz discovered [chaotic solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) to simple meteorological equations. This put paid to any hope of predicting the future course of human societies, which are much more complicated than the weather. So psychohistory is bunk. (Second Foundation, the last book in Asimov's Foundation trilogy, was published in 1953, so Asimov can't be blamed for not knowing about chaos.)